# How do I use a regex method with block?

Tags: ruby, regex, block

What I wanted to do here was insert `um` after every constant. I'll have to pass each character of the string with `um` added, then pass it to a block associated with the method. I don't understand how I can pass the characters down to the block with block instantiation.

```
class Um    
  def to_um( string )
    string.gsub(/(?<=[^aeiou])/, 'um') do |v|
      "#{v}"
    end
  end

  def to_english( string )
    # will output the to_um method back to english
  end
end

Um.to_um( "Watch this get converted to yum!" ) { |v| print v }
```

should output:

```
Wumatumcumhum tumhumisum gumetum cumonumvumerumtumedum tumo yumumum!
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to write a method that takes a block? Or are you asking how to use `String#gsub` with a block?

Comment: I'm asking how to to insert 'um' after every constant in the string using regex, in which is being passed to a block for output. I'm new to ruby so any tip will help. Thanks

Comment: That's too many things for a good Stack Overflow question. Choose one of those, read the documentation about it, then post a question describing what you read and what you don't understand.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. In this case: How would pass the block characters in the method 'to_um' to the instantiation block for the output?

Answer (score 1):

`gsub` works with a block *or* a replacement argument, not both. If you want to use a block to replace the match, you need to omit the second argument:

```
string.gsub(/(?<=[^aeiou])/) { |m| "#{m}um" }
```

Note that there is no need to use a block here, you can include the matched character in the replacement argument using `\1`:

```
string.gsub(/(?<=[^aeiou])/, '\1um')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help meagar! I'll keep that info in mind. So another question,  if I was to use a block here, how would I instantiate that with the passing characters from another block? As in the last line of my code?

Comment: @F.uzzy You wouldn't write code that way. Your code should simply ready `puts Um.to_um('blah blah')`. The value is returned from the function, not passed to a block.

Comment: The first part of the string returned by your second expression is  `"Wumatumcumhum umtumhumisum umgumetum ", yet the desired result is  "Wumatumcumhum tumhumisum gumetum". The problem occurs after each space, as a space matches `[^aeiou]`. You just need to correct the definition of consonants.

Answer (score 1):

```
CONSONANTS = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"

def to_um(str)
  str.gsub(/(?<=[#{CONSONANTS}])/i, 'um')
end

str = "Watch this get converted to yum!"

to_um(str)
  #=> "Watumcumhum tumhumisum gumetum cumonumvumerumtumedum tumo yumumum!"
```

The regex reads, "match a consonant in a positive lookbehind, case-indifferently. If there is a match, the zero length string following the consonant is replaced with `"um"`.